# Unable to use react router

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router-dom

I am not able to use Router even though I am using code directly from sources like https://www.w3schools.com/react/react_router.asp

index.js

```
 import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
 import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
 import Layout from "./pages/Layout";
 import Home from "./pages/Home";
 import Contact from "./pages/Contact";

 export default function App() {
 return (
 <BrowserRouter>
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={<Layout />}>
      <Route index element={<Home />} />
      <Route path="contact" element={<Contact />} />
    </Route>
    </Routes>
  </BrowserRouter>
  );
  }

 ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Layout.js

```
 import { Outlet, Link } from "react-router-dom";

 const Layout = () => {
 return (
  <>
   <nav><ul><li><Link to="/">Home</Link></li>
           <li><Link to="/contact">Contact</Link></li>
       </ul>
   </nav>
   <Outlet />
  </>
)
};
export default Layout;
```

Home.js

```
 const Home = () => {
 return <h1>Home</h1>;
 };
 export default Home;
```

Still, I'm getting this error.

react.development.js:1476

Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:

1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app

**package.json**

```
 {
  "name": "sunalanda",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
  "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.1",
  "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.2",
  "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
  "react": "^17.0.2",
  "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
  "react-scripts": "5.0.0",
  "web-vitals": "^2.1.2"
 },
  "scripts": {
  "start": "react-scripts start",
  "build": "react-scripts build",
  "test": "react-scripts test",
  "eject": "react-scripts eject"
 },
  "eslintConfig": {
  "extends": [
  "react-app",
  "react-app/jest"
]
},
  "browserslist": {
  "production": [
  ">0.2%",
  "not dead",
  "not op_mini all"
],
  "development": [
  "last 1 chrome version",
  "last 1 firefox version",
  "last 1 safari version"
]
}
}
```

[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hg2u7.png)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Also, questions asking about code that isn't working must be accompanied by a [mre] that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] and indicate which line causes the error.

Comment: If I use components in Routes, my page is blank with mentioned errors.  I'm able to use components separately. @Code-Apprentice

Comment: @Agney  I have added code

Comment: What is your node version

Comment: @ANUPSAJJAN v16.13.1

Comment: I see no issue with the code, and I'm unable to reproduce any issue with it copy/pasted into a *running* codesandbox. Please share your package.json file and then also check the installed versions running `npm list react react-dom react-ruoter-dom <package name> etc...`

Comment: @DrewReese I have added my package.json in question.

Answer (score 3):

You appear to be missing `react-router-dom` from your package.json file.

Run `npm install -s react-router-dom` to install ***and*** update/save the dependency to the package.json file.

Kill and restart any development servers, `npm start`.